# Why Linux "system" thread prevent my RT thread from working?

Tags: multithreading, io, linux-kernel, real-time, thread-priority

I have some data acquisition application running under Linux 2.6.37 on DM8148 with TI Linux. I have two threads:

- thread named IDE, scheduled as SCHED_RR, prio 114 (75), which collects data from HW FIFO arriving at 200KiB/s into 30MiB ring buffer each 2ms:

  ```
  while(1) {
    sleep(ms);
    while(DataInFIFO) {
        CollectToRingBuffer();
        SignalToWriter(); }
  }
  ```
- thread WriterIDE, scheduled as SCHED_RR, prio 113 (74), writing this ring buffer in to the USB disk-on-key.

  ```
  while(1) {
    WaitForSignal();
    writeToFileOnDOK();
  }
  ```

I know from measures of `write()` function that sometimes this USB writing may "hang" for some 1.5 and even 2 seconds, trying to write to the DOK. But I was sure that as I gave the collector task 30MiB, which is enough for 150s, everything will be OK.

No! It is not!
I put the time measuring code. And what I see is, that when writer hangs for a long time (f.e.1342ms), then entering the collector thread time also is very large (306ms). This causes HW FIFO overflow and data inconsistency.

I checked the spread of threads priority in the system (ps command) - nothing is real-time, except me. All system tasks are scheduled as OTHER (TS in ps output), even kernel USB threads. Only IRQ tasks are FF, but even them are of lower priority.

I don't know where to go from here... :-(

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for editing! :-)

Comment: IMHO the error might be somewhere else. First thing to come in my mind is, that write() (or something connected) is using a mutex/semaphore to block the ringbuffer => fifo data cannot be written into it. Just for testing, have you tried to create a second ringbuffer containing the exact same data as the first. FIFO writes into the 1st ring and the 2nd ring is written to the USB-DOK. Additionally, can you please tell us if this occurs in some fixed time intervalls or is this random?

Comment: @xMutzelx - thank you. I also thought about such a thing. And all semaphore requests here are with timeout=0 and diagnostics print, which is never printed. Also, I measure separately the FIFO clearance time (which never exceeds 1ms) and time to return to the first(IDE) task. TimeToReturn is huge(>300ms).
As for regularity - no regular timing between events. It may take 40min, 35m. I printout each maximum replacement and huge timings happen from time to time coming up to 1700ms write and 370ms task return time. 
I suppose that this is DOK's issue, which does some internal NAND processing.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the additional informations. Mhm I have done some research and I might have found two other points to try/check. Why is your WriterIDE thread more important (lower priority value) than IDE thread? Lower numbers have higher priority in linux (as far as I know). Secondly how is the so called "nice" value of your threads set?

Comment: Thank you(!) for your willing to help! WriterIDE has lower priority intentionally - I wanted to give highest prio to the IDE task, which needs to run after FIFO, which has limited capacity. Contrary, ring buffer is practically huge allowing WriterIDE to work slowly. That's was my idea...
About the nice value - I don't know. I was sure that nice is relevant for the "normal" tasks, not for real-time - my tasks are created as SCHED_RR. Is nice relevant here?

Comment: How are `SignalToWriter()` and `WaitForSignal()` actually implemented? Do they actually use signals? If so, are you directing and masking the signals correctly? `sleep()` also has interesting interactions with signals.

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist  well, the actual mechanism uses C++ library UCOMMON (https://www.gnu.org/software/commoncpp/). Inside it is implemented with pthread_mutex... To tell the truth I didn't make deep tests, as the library is used in several GNU projects (GNU telephony) and exists from 1999 year...

Comment: You are right, the "nice"-value is unused in your case. My bad! I have another question, can you please execute the command "top" and tell us the "PR" of your threads?

Comment: @xMutzelx - sorry, but I posted it already at the beginning. The IDE task (FIFO collector) has PR 114 (was set in code as 75), while the writer has 113 (was set as 74). Is it what you asked for?

Comment: No, the PR value is between -100 and + 40. The linux priority system is kinda confusing and I just want to make sure that you dont have wrong prioity orders for your threads. Many people mix "PR", "rt_prio" and "niceness" and therfore mix these values.

Comment: @xMutzelx Well, that's what i see under "PRI" when i do "ps -c -T -A". Column CLS contains RR only. Please, remember, that my kernel is rather old (supplied by TI) - 2.6.37.